# Error: incompatible types:byte cannot be converted to Boolean (illegal start of expression)

Tags: java, if-statement

Good morning everyone 
this is my first time using StackOverflow and pretty much my first programming experience.
I'm trying to learn Java and I'm using NetBeans IDE.
while learning about if, conditions and expressions I faced this error that I can't know the cause of.
the guy in my tutorial has it and it's fine and he doesn't have any errors (he's using IntelliJ).
here is my code

```
 byte Temp = 20;
        /*The error shows up here*/ if (Temp => 30){
            System.out.println("It's a Hot day!");
            System.out.println("Drink Alot of Water!");
        }
        else if (Temp > 20)
            System.out.println("It's a Nice day!");
        else 
            System.out.println("It's a Cold day!");
```

I tried with `==` and it worked fine
I'm not sure what the problem is, any help is much appreciated
Thank you very much

Comment: There is no "=<" operator!   Try "<=" ... less or equal to.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC ! Help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Stephen C for the solution

"There is no "=<" operator! Try "<=" ... less or equal to"